# jQuery get height & width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I made an `if` function to check if the width is < 100px. For some reason it hides everything. Anyone know why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pic = $(".pic");

// need to remove these in of case img-element has set width and height
$(".pic").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeAttr("width"); 
    $this.removeAttr("height");

    var pic_real_width = $this.width();
    var pic_real_height = $this.height();
    if(pic_real_width<100){
    $(this).css("display","none");
    }
    });

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pic").each(function() {
        var pic = $( this );
        pic.removeAttr("width"); 
        pic.removeAttr("height");

        var pic_real_width = pic.width();
        var pic_real_height = pic.height();
        alert(pic_real_width);
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.
 var pic_real_width = $this.width();
 var pic_real_height = $this.height();
    if(pic_real_width<100){
 $(".pic").css("display","none");
 }
Hides all images. Any ideea why it doesn;t apply to that particular condition?

Comment: see my answer to your latest question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873536/jquery-height-condition/1873546#1873546
I've answered you there.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `pic` when you should be using `$(this)`:

```
$(".pic").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeAttr("width"); 
    $this.removeAttr("height");

    var pic_real_width = $this.width();
    var pic_real_height = $this.height();
    alert(pic_real_width);
     });
```

You should also watch for images that are resized with CSS.

Instead of

```
    $this.removeAttr("width"); 
    $this.removeAttr("height");
```

try

```
$this.css({width: 'auto', height: 'auto'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried every solutions here but none worked for me so I created my own script and it works in all browsers including IE. Heres my script:

```
$(function(){
 var sbar = $(".sidebar").outerHeight(true);
 var pcont = $(".post_content").outerHeight(true);
if(sbar < pcont){
  $(".sidebar").css("min-height",pcont+"px");
}
});

/*** CSS ***/

.sidebar{
   float:left;
   min-height: 500px;
   width:180px;
}

.post_content{
   float:left;
   min-height: 500px;
   width:593px;
}
```

I hope this will work with you too!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this.css({width: 'auto', height: 'auto'});
```

try it